# Why DatasourceRequest is not passed on toolbar's custom command in Kendo Grid

Tags: c#, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I try to create a custom command button on toolbar in Kendo Grid. The code is like

```
Html.Kendo().Grid...
.ToolBar(commands => commands.Custom().Text("Export").Action("ExportAthletePageToExcel", "ExportExcelButton", new { selectedSportId = Model.CurrentSport, yearId = Model.CurrentYear }))
...
Controller is like,
public ActionResult ExportAthletePageToExcel(DataSourceRequest request, string selectedSportId, string yearId)
...
```

It works for parameters like selectedSportId and yearId, except request does not have right info for grid (filter, sort, page and etc). I'd like to know what is the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I indirectly stumbled across a solution to this that I like. Telerik has a demo posted for exporting a grid's contents to Excel. They use a custom command, and set the DataSourceRequest parameters in javascript on the client side using the OnDataBound event of the grid. I've put together the relevant bits here for you...

1. Include the four DataSourceRequest parameters in the Action's routevalues, but with placeholder tildes which will be replaced in step 2:

   ```
   .ToolBar(commands => commands.Custom().Text("Export").Action("ExportAthletePageToExcel", "ExportExcelButton", new { page = "~", pageSize = "~", filter = "~", sort = "~", selectedSportId = Model.CurrentSport, yearId = Model.CurrentYear }))
   ```
2. Include a call to a javascript function in the DataBound event:

   ```
   .Events(ev => ev.DataBound("onDataBound"))
   ```
3. then add the following script to the page:

   ```
   function onDataBound(e) {
   var grid = this;

   // ask the parameterMap to create the request object for you
   var requestObject = (new kendo.data.transports["aspnetmvc-server"]({ prefix: "" }))
   .options.parameterMap({
       page: grid.dataSource.page(),
       sort: grid.dataSource.sort(),
       filter: grid.dataSource.filter()
   });

   // Get the export link as jQuery object
   var $exportLink = grid.element.find('.export');
   // Get its 'href' attribute - the URL where it would navigate to
   var href = $exportLink.attr('href');
   // Update the 'page' parameter with the grid's current page
   href = href.replace(/page=([^&]*)/, 'page=' + requestObject.page || '~');
   // Update the 'sort' parameter with the grid's current sort descriptor
   href = href.replace(/sort=([^&]*)/, 'sort=' + requestObject.sort || '~');
   // Update the 'pageSize' parameter with the grid's current pageSize
   href = href.replace(/pageSize=([^&]*)/, 'pageSize=' + grid.dataSource._pageSize);
   //update filter descriptor with the filters applied
   href = href.replace(/filter=([^&]*)/, 'filter=' + (requestObject.filter || '~'));
   // Update the 'href' attribute
   $exportLink.attr('href', href);
   ```

   }
4. Now in your controller method you'll have access to the DataSourceRequest with all the relevant parameters populated with the current state. Also note that you're missing the attribute `[DataSourceRequest]` in your method's request parameter so it should look like this:

   ```
   public ActionResult ExportAthletePageToExcel([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string selectedSportId, string yearId)
   ```

Comment: ...as for why they didn't use dataSource.pageSize() and instead they fetch it from the non-futureproof _pageSize, I can't say. But I did try it the "correct" way and it didn't work, so I suspect this is a known issue and needs to be done this way.

Comment: I also find another solution that use Kendo.Mvc.Gridcommand. Its advantage is that you don't need to do the replace stuffs. Just use Kendo.Mvc.GridCommand.Parse to create a Gridcommand. There is no such command for DataSourceRequest which I think is a miss.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a custom Toolbar is supposed to send the datasourcerequest, you can try doing it with javascript though.

For example:

```
function exportAthletePageToExcel(){
   var dataSource = $('#YourGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource;
   var dataSourceRequest = dataSource.transport.parameterMap({
        filter: dataSource.filter(),
        page: dataSource.page(),
        pageSize: dataSource.pageSize(),
        sort: dataSource.sort()
   });

   var data = "";
   for (var key in dataSourceRequest) {
       if (dataSourceRequest[key] !== undefined) {
           data += key + "=" + dataSourceRequest[key] + "&";
       }
   }

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF",
        url: '@Html.Action("ExportAthletePageToExcel", "ExportExcelButton", new { selectedSportId = Model.CurrentSport, yearId = Model.CurrentYear })',
        data: data,
        success: function(){
            dataSource.read();
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: It can not reach controller. I think url may have problem. I am not using Razor. Is it Html.Actionlink or Url.Action or something else? So far, none of them are working.